# how to get rid of the denominator in the squareroot, that appears in the denominator?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Here is an example:  $\frac{\nu  y_0}{\left(x_0+\frac{1}{2}\right) \sqrt{\nu ^2+\frac{\left(4 x_0^2+4 y_0^2-1\right){}^2}{16 y_0^2}}}$

```
 test=(\[Nu] Subscript[y, 0])/((1/2+Subscript[x, 0]) Sqrt[\[Nu]^2+(-1+4 Subsuperscript[x, 0, 2]+4 Subsuperscript[y, 0, 2])^2/(16 Subsuperscript[y, 0, 2])])
```

I'd like to get rid of the denominator in the squareroot. I tried separating the numerator and denominator, and multiply both by $4y_0$
 or $\sqrt{16y_0^2}$. Somehow neither works. Strangely, even if I multiply the denominator by $\sqrt{16y_0^2}$, the two terms won't combine together even if I use Simplify.

Currently I use `FullSimplify[test,Subscript[y, 0]>0]`, which does not work. Hence, I had to copy the material in the squareroot, multiply by $16y_0^2$, simplify it  separately, then plug back the original expression to obtain the results (the numerator will be multiplied by $4y_0$, too).

I wonder if there is any better way to do this mor efficiently?

Comment: How about using a rule `test /. {1/(16 Subsuperscript[y,0,2]) -> 1}`

Comment: This also might be a bit more generic `test /. {1/ Sqrt[x_ + a_*y_/z_] -> 1/Sqrt[x + y]}`

Comment: A part of your problem is that you use `Subsuperscript[y, 0, 2]` instead of `Subscript[y, 0]^2`. `Superscript` is not a power, it is to make an upper index. You can make sure of it looking at `FullForm[test]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
test = (ν y)/((1/2 + 
      x) Sqrt[ν^2 + (-1 + 4 x^2 + 4 y^2)^2/(16 y^2)]);

test2 = MapAt[Together[#] &, test, {4, 1}]
test3 = MapAt[Hold, test2, {5, 1, 2}] // Simplify[#, y > 0] & //ReleaseHold
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry, @Alexei Boulbitch, but this result is not true for negative y.  `% /. {x -> 3, y -> -2, \[Nu] -> 4}` yields `128/(35 Sqrt[145])` whereas  `test /. {x -> 3, y -> -2, \[Nu] -> 4}` yields `-(128/(35 Sqrt[145]))` .

Comment: Have you noticed that I simplified with the condition `y>0`. For negative y values one simplifies with another condition. Generally, I only show the way of operation, not the exhaustive solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
test = (\[Nu] y)/((1/2 + 
   x) Sqrt[\[Nu]^2 + (-1 + 4 x^2 + 4 y^2)^2/(16 y^2)]);

test // Together // 
        PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> y \[Element] Reals && y != 0] &
```

[image]